# How to draw SLD tree for this query

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, sld-resolution

a ↔ b
　↙  ↑
c → d

```
path(X, X, Y).                                  
path(X, Y, s(Z)) :- edge(X, A), path(A, Y, Z).  
path(X, Y, Z) :- eps(X, A), path(A, Y, Z).      
edge(a, b).
edge(b, a).
edge(c, d).
edge(d, b).
eps(b, c).
```

And `path(X,Y,k)` is `true` if there is a path from `X` to `Y` in the graph where at most `k` non-ℇ-edges are used along the path.
How can I draw an SLD tree for the query `?-path(a,a,s(s(0)).` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but it should look somewhat like this

[image]